# Salesforce VF - getContent() and getContentAsPdf() timeout

Tags: visualforce, getcontentaspdf

How to set extent default timeout for getContent and getContentAsPdf? Those are considered as callouts so I assume it should be possible to set timeout.
We are using them to generate PDF files from custom VF page. But on production we are getting quite frequently timeout. So the timeout extension might help..

Comment: are you generating only 1 PDF per transaction? or more than one? Are you displaying long lists in these PDFs?  Basically, what is the variable that determines a timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the time out won't help you; you're presumably running in to the CPU governor limit if you've gone more than 10 seconds. Your only choice is to optimize your page and/or controller in order to get under the 10 second limit.